# Executing another java program from our java program

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute a Java program from our Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502494/execute-a-java-program-from-our-java-program)

I wanted to execute another java program from our java program. When i run a java program called 'First.java', it should prompt the user to enter the name of any class name(.java file name) and then it should read that input(.java file) and should be able to compile and run that program.Can anyone give me a sample code for that?

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific, can you post part or all of both Java programs? And then show us where you want to call the other Java program

Comment: What do you mean by `execute`? Do you want the program to start up in its own JVM as if it was launched from the command line? Do you just want to execute a part of the code from your own program? Do you want to have the program running as a separate process in your current program's JVM?

Comment: @JohnB Yes, i wanted the program to start as if it was launched from the command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if the other java program is an executable program,you can just use code like this:

```
    try 
    { 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\my.exe"); 
    }
catch(IOException ex) 
    { }
```

Comment: I prefer `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime.exec` because its API is easier to use

Comment: -1 a poor answer (both in process & execution) to a poorly asked question.  Don't try this at home, kids (and if you do, put a great deal more effort into writing it)!

Comment: **this is the most outdated ( and incorrect ) answer on this question! Do not follow this answer! Look below for current idiomatic ways to do this!**

Answer (score 4):

It isn't clear from the question, but I will assume the *other Java program* is a command line program.

If this is the case you would use `Runtime.exec()`.

It isn't quite that simple if you want to see what the output of that program is.
Below is how you would use `Runtime.exec()` with any external program, not just a Java program.

First you need a non-blocking way to read from `Standard.out` and `Standard.err`

```
private class ProcessResultReader extends Thread
{
    final InputStream is;
    final String type;
    final StringBuilder sb;

    ProcessResultReader(@Nonnull final InputStream is, @Nonnull String type)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                this.sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (final IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then you need to tie this class into the respective `InputStream` and `OutputStream`objects.

```
    try
    {
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", query));
        final ProcessResultReader stderr = new ProcessResultReader(p.getErrorStream(), "STDERR");
        final ProcessResultReader stdout = new ProcessResultReader(p.getInputStream(), "STDOUT");
        stderr.start();
        stdout.start();
        final int exitValue = p.waitFor();
        if (exitValue == 0)
        {
            System.out.print(stdout.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.print(stderr.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (final InterruptedException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

This is pretty much the boiler plate I use when I need to `Runtime.exec()` anything in Java.

A more advanced way would be to use `FutureTask` and `Callable` or at least `Runnable` rather than directly extending `Thread` which isn't the best practice.

**NOTE:**

The `@Nonnull` annotations are in the JSR305 library. If you are using Maven, and you are using Maven aren't you, just add this dependency to your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Call the other program's `main` method (or whatever is the entry point in the other program)
- or use `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: +1 The second program is a Java program, and the poster's description shows no reason `SecondProgramClass.main(...)` couldn't be invoked programmatically.

Comment: It would most likely be more efficient to call the other program's main method as then there's no need to create a new process, which is relatively expensive. I suppose there might be issues of collisions between the two apps, like if they had classes with the same name.