# Execute external program through terminal in Java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have an external program [Otter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otter_%28theorem_prover%29) that gets as parameter some filename and creates an output file, also specified as parameter.
So for example if my input is "proof.in" and I want my output to be placed in the "proof.out" file, I run the following command in the terminal:

```
otter <proof.in >proof.out
```

The "proof.in" file must be in the same file as the otter executable.

The problem is that I need this functionality from Java so in my Java code I do the following:

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("otter <proof.in >proof.out")
```

but after this line the whole UI is frozen and nothing happens and no output file is generated.

Could anyone show me where I got it wrong??

Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Comment: Does your program expect some user input? If so, it will be waiting for the input..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing another java program from our java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770094/executing-another-java-program-from-our-java-program)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal: you are attempting to launch a command normally issued by a shell.

Here, `<proof.in` and `>proof.out` are taken as literal arguments to the `otter` executable, and not shell redirections. But seeing the home page for this tool, it will not work: it expects data on stdin, which the redirect normally provides.

You need to launch this command via a shell, and preferably using a process builder:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "otter <proof.in >proof.out");
final Process p = pb.start();
```

etc etc.

You should also ensure, of course, that the program runs from the correct directory -- fortunately, `ProcessBuilder` also allows you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7770167/177800) to another question with a very detailed answer on how to do this correctly in an async way with threads. This is the only way to not block your main thread and hang your GUI.

```
private class ProcessResultReader extends Thread
{
    final InputStream is;
    final String type;
    final StringBuilder sb;

    ProcessResultReader(@Nonnull final InputStream is, @Nonnull String type)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                this.sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (final IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.sb.toString();
    }
}
```

then you use the above class like so

```
try
{
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", query));
    final ProcessResultReader stderr = new ProcessResultReader(p.getErrorStream(), "STDERR");
    final ProcessResultReader stdout = new ProcessResultReader(p.getInputStream(), "STDOUT");
    stderr.start();
    stdout.start();
    final int exitValue = p.waitFor();
    if (exitValue == 0)
    {
        System.out.print(stdout.toString());
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.print(stderr.toString());
    }
}
catch (final IOException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
catch (final InterruptedException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run the program, do always remember this:
`Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("cmd /c dir");
p.waitFor();`

Answer (score -1):

You could see what is happening when you execute your command:

```
   try {
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("cmd /c dir");

        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));

        String aux = br.readLine();

        while (aux!=null) {
            System.out.println (aux);

            aux = br.readLine();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

with this code.