# How to execute my own commands on terminal from java File

Tags: java, terminal, ros

I am trying to make a eclipse project in Java to launch commands with some buttons. The libraries of Ros fuerte (These ones i want to use) are correctly installed and concretly i am trying to launch a ros command from a Java File using:

```
String cmd = "roscore";

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
```

If i launch this command from a current terminal it works, but if i do it from the java file i have a problem because the terminal doesnt recognize the command.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "roscore": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
at LaunchTerminal.main(LaunchTerminal.java:24)
```

I think that i need to add some path or similar but i dont find the information. Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank u.

Comment: launch program with absolute path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute external program through terminal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751337/execute-external-program-through-terminal-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

only normal commands are possible to execute like rm or cd ... al others must be referenced with full path of context

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, but the terminal closes when it executes the command. Is it possible to keep it open?

Comment: why you want to keep it open?

but here an nice site http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html

Comment: I need it because its a program (master) with whom all the rest ot the "nodes" of Ros are connected, so i need it to be opened.

Comment: is roscore an command which you can use everywhere in the terminal? if yes ... i have no idea why that doesnt work ... else ... you have to use the fully qualified path and name of this script

Answer (score 0):

Do the following if you are using the groovy distribution:

```
String cmd = "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash && roscore";
```