# Execution of Program from Program with Time Constraints (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, process, timeout

I'm trying to make program which runs some executable program(call it `p`), given time limit `t` ms. It does following tasks:

1. If program `p` has executed normally, print it's output to console.
2. If program `p` couldn't execute completely within time limit, print `"Sorry, needs more time!"` and then terminate execution of `p`.
3. If program `p` has terminated abnormally (e.g. `RuntimeError`), print `"Can I've some debugger?"`

I'm using `ProcessResultReader` class in the following program from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7770167/3922867). My program is working as long as `p` finishes it's execution normally or terminate abnormally. But, it doesn't terminate if `p` itself doesn't terminate after `timeout`.(Try `p` with simple `while(true)` loop with no exit condition). It seems that thread `stdout` is alive even after execution of `stdout.stop()`. What am I doing wrong in this code?

Thanks.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.*;

class ProcessResultReader extends Thread
{

    final InputStream is;
    final StringBuilder sb;

    ProcessResultReader(final InputStream is)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                this.sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (final IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int t = 1000; 
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); //cmd is command to execute program p 
        ProcessResultReader stdout = new ProcessResultReader(p.getInputStream());
        stdout.start();
        if(!p.waitFor(t, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        {
            stdout.stop();
            p.destroy();
            System.out.println("Sorry, needs more time!");
        }
        else
        {
            if(p.exitValue()==0) System.out.println(stdout.toString());
            else System.out.println("Can I've some debugger?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2733370/1858327) isn't exactly what you're looking for but it seems like it could help or at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

According to java docs,
stdout.stop() was deprecated and even stdout.destroy() is never implemented.

For more information, see Why are Thread.stop, [Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

you could try this instead.

```
String cmd="cmd /c sleep 5";
    int timeout = 1; 
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); //cmd is command to execute program p 
    ProcessResultReader stdout = new ProcessResultReader(p.getInputStream());
    stdout.start();
    if(!p.waitFor(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    {
        stdout.stop();
        p.destroy();
        System.out.println("Sorry, needs more time!");
        System.out.flush();
    }
    else
    {
        if(p.exitValue()==0) System.out.println(stdout.toString());
        else System.out.println("Can I've some debugger?");
    }
```

Comment: I'm aware that `stop()` is deprecated. Note that I want to terminate execution of `p` when timeout occurs, not main. else, I would have used `System.exit`.